# Redirect user after one-time-login

Tags: 8, rules, redirection

When users get an email with one time login link, they will arrive on a page to set their password (separated form via [Password Separate Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/change_pwd_page))
But once they click submit, it doesn't redirect them to the normal view of the profile page.

How should I make the redirect? 
I tried different Rules ([Test 1](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/480584), [Test 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/2975452)) and I even wrote to the module support of Password Separate Form, but nobody answer me and I need to fix the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect after user login](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195170/redirect-after-user-login)

Comment: That's the problem, nothing works from that page, because I have Password Separate From on. And I can't uninstalled it, it need to be a separate page.

Answer (score 1):

For people that want to have a separate form, here is my own solution:

I deinstalled Password Separate Form and, instead, installed [Password Reset Landing Page (PRLP)](https://www.drupal.org/project/prlp)
It does the redirect, the separate form and make sure people don't forget to actually set the new password.