# Automatically load pending draft

Tags: webforms

I'm using drupal 8 and webform module (multistep). In the webform submission settings, i enabled submit several drafts which adds the 'save' button for saving the progress.
When the user logs out and logs in later on, a messsage to 'load pending draft' appears. In my settings, each user is allowed one submission. Is there a way to automatically load pending drafts without clicking on the link in the said message?

Appreciate any help given, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is. When a user's saves draft a token gets generated. You need to get their token value.

```
$webform_submission = \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission\WebformSubmission::load($sid);
$token = $webform_submission->getToken();
```

Then, you need to generate a URL like this

```
$draft_url = '/form/webform-name?token=' . $token
```

and on login [redirect them to that url](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195170/redirect-after-user-login).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, would you plz let me know where to place the code above?

Comment: @ram_griever well depends on where you want to do the redirect. Either hook_user_login or hook_user_view. PS: the code above is not all complete, you still need to query the db to get the `$sid` (submission id) that belongs to the currently logged in user.

Comment: Alright thanks, will try it and get back to you

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply, i've figured it out without coding, it was in the webform submission settings, click 'limit users to one weborm entity' and then select 'authenticated users' in the section 'Allow users to save and finish the webform later' and that was it, let me know if it works out

Comment: @ram_griever I assumed you already did that... did that solve your `Is there a way to automatically load pending drafts without clicking on the link in the said message?` issue? 

Comment: yup, it did, when i login, i already have the latest draft auto-filled

Comment: @ram_griever oh I see, but you still must have done a redirect to the form, because the default behavior after login in is the user page.

Comment: in the basic settings, i've defined the 403 (login page) and 404 (the initial webform), plus the default front page is the webform intended

Comment: However, I still have a problem, Drupal 8 'allow one webform submission per user' doesn't work, so I'll post that in a related forum or try to figure it out later on, see, I intend to block a user upon a complete submisson, not a draft one...didn't figure that out yet